# No cambia el precio en los productos hijos Magento 2

Tags: magento2

En los productos configurables en el producto padre, cambia el precio  al aumentar la cantidad del producto como muestro en las siguientes imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando selecciono la presentación muestra el valor del producto   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al modificar la cantidad del producto el valor me queda en cero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En consola o en el log de magento no me registra ningun error.
En el carrito de compras me aparecen los datos de forma correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalizo la compra y muestra los valores correctos de cantidad y precio.

Comment: ¿qué versión exacta de Magento utilizas? ¿algún theme comprado o es totalmente custom?

Comment: Version de magento 2.1.5, con un theme comprado

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que responder de forma puntual es un poco difícil, pues hay muchos factores que tienen que ver con la forma como se actualizan los valores, cantidades, imágenes y stock de los productos configurables al momento de hacer alguna selección.

En un proyecto tuvimos bastantes problemas con dicha sección, y fue necesario hacer módulos que solucionaran ciertos bugs que tenía el core de Magento y el Theme que había comprado el cliente.

---

En caso que el problema solo tenga que ver con el front-end del sitio, el archivo indicado es swatch-renderer.js, del módulo Magento Swatches, hay una función que actualiza el precio, en la cual puedes haces tu debugging para determinar si el error es en ese punto o en el código de servidor:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js#L687

```
    /**
     * Update total price
     *
     * @private
     */
    _UpdatePrice: function () {
        var $widget = this,
            $product = $widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct),
            $productPrice = $product.find(this.options.selectorProductPrice),
            options = _.object(_.keys($widget.optionsMap), {}),
            result;

        $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[option-selected]').each(function () {
            var attributeId = $(this).attr('attribute-id');

            options[attributeId] = $(this).attr('option-selected');
        });

        result = $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[_.findKey($widget.options.jsonConfig.index, options)];

        $productPrice.trigger(
            'updatePrice',
            {
                'prices': $widget._getPrices(result, $productPrice.priceBox('option').prices)
            }
        );

        if (result.oldPrice.amount !== result.finalPrice.amount) {
            $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).show();
        } else {
            $(this.options.slyOldPriceSelector).hide();
        }
```

---

Si el problema va más allá del front-end, intenta desactivando el theme personalizado y utiliza Luma, si el problema sigue, entonces es del core de Magento y tal vez debas corregir algún aspecto del código PHP, tal vez debas revisar los siguientes archivos:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/app/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php